# Windows 10: Having Window on multiple, BUT NOT ALL desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

The use case is that I like having more than 2 desktops. One for everything, one for work, one for a hobby - I want to have an application show on my hobby and 'everything' desktop, but NOT on my work desktop.

Right-clicking in the virtual desktop screen gives you the option to move windows, or to show them on ALL desktops, what I would need is the functionality of an "also show on desktopName" similar to what already exists in "move to".

Is this a hidden option somewhere? Is there an alternative way to make this work?

Comment: No hidden or alternative way I'm aware of. It is as it always has been one or all.